# Get request not sent

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, get

I'm new to MVC and writing a web app on MVC. I'm trying to send a get request.
I've got a razor page from which I'm trying to send a request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var query = $('#productQuery').val();
    alert("Start.");
    var uri = 'api/search/products?q=abc';
    $.get(uri, function (data) {
            alert("Load was performed.");
    });
});
```

Besides I've got a controller linked to the page which works absolutely fine, and this ApiController:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/search")]
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    [Route("products")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDocument>> searchProducts(
        [FromUri(Name = "q")]string query,
        [FromUri(Name = "cat")]string[] categories=null)
    {
        ProductsResponse response = await SolrWebApi.QueryAsync<ProductsResponse>(query);
        if (response.Header.Status != 0)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        return response.Body.Documents.Take(3).ToArray();
    }
```

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong and why my get request not sent.

Comment: Your uri should be `api/search/products` given the routing attributes.  You might like to look into `@Url.Action` to get the url via controller+action rather than hardcode the route.  If it still doesn't work, try it without the `categories` parameter (or with zero parameters and build up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are new to Web API, you need to debug in both client and server.

Good practice is to use default route first before using route attributes.

```
public class SearchProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get([FromUri(Name = "q")] string query)
    {
        return new[] {"value1-" + query, "value2-" + query};
    }
}
```

**Testing URL:** http://localhost:xxxx/Api/SearchProducts?q=abc

If you can get the API working, you can go back to client side.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var query = $('#productQuery').val();
    alert("Start.");
    var uri = 'api/SearchProducts?q=abc';
    $.get(uri, function (data) {
        alert("Load was performed.");
    });
});
```

`[FromUri(Name = "cat")]string[] categories=null` If you want to send array, you want to use ***HttpPost*** instead of ***HttpGet***.

Comment: I've got SearchProductsController which is just a simple mvc controller
And SearchController which is ApiController
so should the uri look like api/Search?q=abc ?

Comment: ***Controller*** name should be ***noun***, and ***Action*** method name should be ***verb***. Please follow the general naming conventions. Make both API and client-side work with static values before returning data from database or third party API.

Answer (score 0):

var uri = 'api/search.products?q=abc';

it has the issue it should be

var uri = 'api/search/products?q=abc';

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript code you should use @Url.Action to build correct path as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var query = $('#productQuery').val();
alert("Start.");
var uri = '@Url.Action("searchProducts","SearchController")' + '?q=abc';
$.get(uri, function (data) {
        alert("Load was performed.");
});
});
```